# how to change an icon on click in meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, meteor

In meteor, I am trying to change icon change on click (I used glyphicon Icons) to add favourites to list. I used toggleClass(). But it is not working,. Here I am attaching my code. When I refresh the page the icon is not changing. Can anyone help me with solution.
HTML Code:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty" style="color:green"></span>
```

And JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.glyphicon').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('glyphicon-star-empty glyphicon-star');
    });
});
```

Comment: It' working fine.. are you add jquery.js ? check this link: https://jsfiddle.net/w42mr1ju/

Comment: 1) check min.js file. include or not.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you do this:

```
Template.TemplateName.events({
    "click .glyphicon": function(event){
         $(event.currentTarget).toggleClass('glyphicon-star-empty glyphicon-star');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define an event:

```
Template.YourTemplateName.events({
  "click .glyphicon": function(){
    $(event.target).toggleClass('glyphicon-star-empty glyphicon-star');
  }
});
```

Comment: `this` will be the template's data context, not the DOM element. You need `$(event.target).toggleClass()`

Comment: Right @MichelFloyd

Answer (score 0):

This should work:
    `Template.TemplateName.events({
    $('.glyphicon').click(function(){
    $(event.currentTarget).toggleClass('glyphicon-star-empty glyphicon-star');
    });`